# I have a piece of video software that logs data streams consecutively with the video. What is/are the mechanism(s)?

Tags: video, mp4

I have a video system where files are generated in the .mp4* video format. There is only one video stream, one audio stream, and no subtitle track.
However the video files have several interleaved data streams readable by special software.

What mechanism(s) are available to thread data into a video file that are transparent to generic video playback systems?

```
* VLC Data:
  Stream 0:
    Codec: H264 - MPEG-4-AVC (part 10) (avc1)
    Language: English
    Type: Video
    Video resolution: 1280x720
    Frame rate: 30.406770
    Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
    Orientation: Top left
    Chroma information: Left
  Stream 1
    Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4)
    Language: English
    Type: Audio
    Channels: Stereo
    Sample rate: 44100 Hz
    Bits per sample: 32
```

Comment: What type of _"several interleaved data streams"_? Are we talking about text Strings as the logged data? Anyways you can put customised metadata (which could be text) inside an MP4 file.

Comment: Basically imagine something like a numeric signal, logged at 10 samples per second, time aligned to the video.

Comment: Since no-one is answering I'll throw my experience in there. Hope it's useful to you. PS: I think you got down-voted because its difficult to answer this without an example file.

Answer (score 3):

> *"I have a video system where files are generated in the **.mp4** video format...
>  Imagine something like a numeric signal, logged at
> 10 samples per second, time aligned to the video"*
>
> - *"However the video files have several interleaved data streams readable by special software."*
> - *"What mechanism(s) are available to thread data into a video file that are transparent to generic video playback systems?"*

**(1)** It's **possible to add extra bytes** at the end of a sample's bytes. The signal decoding software only has to know where to find those bytes and then just read/process them.

(*In **H.264** a sample / NALU can be a video frame or metadata like H.264's **SPS**, **PPS** and **SEI** data*).

- It can know by checking the bytes for expected frame data boundaries. For example checking how many slices make a full frame and then adding custom bytes at the ending of a last slice's bytes.
- It can know by checking for a sample's specific **NALU type**. For example in the H.264 specs it says that **sample type 17 & 18** are **reserved**. This makes it possible to store custom data here using entire NAL unit. The ending of custom data is known when a new frame/NALU's start code is found.

Below is an [image of MP4 with custom data (text/digits) added to a frame's bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVMNI.png). 
This type of **edited file** is still playable on most players (where for me, *"most"* is actually all of my tested players like VLC, MPC Home Cinema, Windows Film/TV player, and also Chrome and Firefox as browser tests).

[image]

The original bytes (a colour block of 16x16 video resolution) in H.264 are:
 `00 00 00 01 41 9A A0 33 D4` 
*where:* 
The `00 00 00 01` is a sample's Start code and `41 9A A0 33 D4` is the actual P-frame video data.

After adding text *"testing 123"* the following bytes now exist:
 `00 00 00 00 74 65 73 74 69 6E 67 20 31 32 33`.

In your file you need to check if the custom data is added within the video frames themselves (at H.264 data level) or else if they exist within the container itself (at MP4 data level)

**(2)** It's difficult to say what your video system's file is doing, **without checking**, but some possibilities:

- **The data is directly appended into a video frame's bytes**: Most decoders will safely skip extra bytes that are within the **sample size** (in MP4) but are beyond the codec's data length of bytes (in H264).
  For example: An H.264 frame from codec is **80 bytes** long but frame size in MP4 is written as **100 bytes**. The player can decode those valid/expected 80 bytes and then skip to byte `100+1` to get to next frame.
- **The data is placed into a "Reserved" NAL Unit's bytes**: No MPEG decoder is expecting any data from such a frame, so it becomes a possible location to store custom data bytes that are ignored by normal video players. The signal decoder can just check the "size of sample" and then read that much length of "sample data" bytes to extract the signal.
- **The data is stored in a custom atom**: It is possible to create custom named atoms in an MP4. Since an atom's declaration includes size and name, any decoders not recognising the **atom name** can just skip according to the **atom size** until an expected atom is found.
- **The data is stored in UDTA atom**: It is added into the custom metadata section of an MP4 container (called **udta** or "user data atom"). Since this would be a single large entry holding all of the logged signals, they (on special software side) must have a way to separate each signal's data per frame (maybe each signal starts with a related frame number? or maybe has timestamp for when to display?).
   PS: Your signals would be visible to some players that also read this metadata (UDTA) section.
- **The data is stored in FREE atom**: Another possible place (apart from "**udta**" atom) is to store custom metadata in the "**free**" atom, since it is kept reserved as "free" space (*eg:* if you expect  in future that your MP4's header data will change to a larger length that spills into such needed free space). Usually the "sample data" part is filled with only zeroes, so why not add some custom data here?
- **The data is stored as ID3 metadata**: If your MP4 is actually **fragmented** (but the chunks are joined as one file) then it's possible that your file uses the **ID3** or even **emsg** method to store any side/extra data. See [this Wowza streaming guide for a concept explanation](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-timed-metadata-in-wowza-live-streaming-workflows#what-is-timed-metadata-0).
  PS: Your signals would be visible to some players that can read ID3 metadata from video files.